# PHP 7.3 upgrade - strange behavior mysql transactions

Tags: php, mysql

## update

I seem to have found out what the problem is.. If I do a `commit` and `begin` just before fetching the data with the plain SQL query it works..

But why? I didn't need to to this before the upgrade.. What has changed in PHP (or PDO)?

---

I have a test where I test all features in my application

How it works.

1. First I do a `curl` (to localhost) to insert some data via the application API.
2. Immediately after (in the same script) I check the data in the database (just by doing a plain SQL query).

But the data is not visible? If I copy/paste the SQL to phpmyadmin the new record is fetched

Have upgraded from `PHP7.0` to `PHP7.3` and I use PDO (mysqli)

```
// run an insert method to the application API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// immediately after (in the same script) fetching the data from the database with plain SQL query (empty result)
\DB::commit(); // <-- this commit
\DB::begin(); // <-- and this begin solves it
$dbh = \DB::get_dbh();
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM block WHERE id='.$output['id'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$res = $sth->fetch();
echo "sql: $sql\n";
var_dump($res);

// if I copy/paste the same SQL query to phpmyadmin the record is found (or run it from a new script)
```

I think its a bit strange. It's like the mysql transaction is not commited even when the `curl` is done and closed?

This has never been a problem before I upgraded to PHP 7.3

No errors in any logs `/var/log/php7.3-fpm.log`, `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: have you enabled errors and checked logs?

Comment: the row in mysql is there.. If I copy/paste the query and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: So show us the code that this CURL will cause to run

Comment: Did you just upgrade PHP or did you upgrade anything else as well?

Comment: @clarkk that doesn't mean there isn't other errors ..

Comment: Sounds like you DIDN'T check you error log! Thats always the first thing to do

Comment: Which logs do you want me to check? The data is saved in the database

Comment: I have just upgraded PHP

Comment: How did you upgrade php ? And had you previously manualy install phpX.X.X curl ?

Comment: PHP Error log and MySQL Error log and Apache Error log

Comment: are you using `mysql` or `mysqli` for your queries? As mysql is deprecated, your upgraded version will not support mysql

Comment: What version of PHP did you upgrade from?

Comment: I use PDO and mysqli

Comment: `PHP 7.0` > `PHP7.3`

Comment: Are you going to show us the Script that gets run by this Curl?

Comment: No errors in any logs `/var/log/php7.3-fpm.log`, `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: Apache has its own error log, so does nginx. PHP (fpm) has an error log too and various frameworks have their own logs - you check all of those.  Did you try to manually hit one of the URLs that are responsible for working with the database? Are you checking http response status codes? Maybe you're having php segfaulting (happened to me with 7.3) so nothing gets executed.

Comment: @mjh, the `curl` request works `HTTP 200` and the record is inserted into the database..

Comment: So what issue are we trying to identify here? You started this by saying ___It's like the mysql transaction is not commited even when the curl is done___

Comment: ___Whats the point___ in preparing a query that you have already concatenated variables into?

Comment: Have updated my question with some more code..

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't mind the query.. It was just for a quick post... the query does what is expected

Comment: By any chance, are you using some type of mysql replication? Something like writing to a master server and reading from a slave?

Comment: @CosminStaicu actually I have a master/slave replication.. but I think I have found the problem.. If I do a `commit/begin` just before the SQL query.. it works.. but why??

Comment: have updated my quesion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to commit so the mysql connection didn't run a transaction.. see the update in the question